# AWS SNS - boto3 - Specify TemplateId and EntityId

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns

The following code works to send a message with a sender id but how do I specify a **TemplateId** and **EntityId**? These two fields were added recently and are required to send SMS messages to destinations in India. It's done with the message attributes but I cannot figure out the syntax/keys.

```
client.publish(PhoneNumber=phone, Message=message,
 MessageAttributes={
 'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {
   'DataType': 'String',
   'StringValue': 'SenderID'
  },
 'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': {
   'DataType': 'String',
   'StringValue': 'Transactional'
 }})
```

**AWS.SNS.SMS.TemplateId** and **AWS.SNS.SMS.TemplateID** keys don't work.

I this error get:

> Message attribute names starting with 'AWS.' or 'Amazon.' are reserved for use by Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html), the correct keys to use are `AWS.MM.SMS.EntityId` and `AWS.MM.SMS.TemplateId`.